# Proving convergence in $L^p$ norm for $0<p<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Define $T_\theta : \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ by $T_\theta(x,y)=(x \cos{\theta}+y\sin{\theta}, -x\sin{\theta}+y\cos{\theta})$. To prove that for $0<p<\infty$ and $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$
$$||f \circ T_\theta - f||_p \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{as} \ \theta \rightarrow 0$$

Managed to prove this for $1\leq p < \infty$ using density of $C_0^\infty$ in $L^p$. How to deal with the case $0<p<1$? Or maybe some other approach should be considered? Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure continuous functions w compact support are dense in all the $L^p$ spaces under consideration.

Comment: @zhw I thought about it, but so far can't find any reference... I checked some books and lecture notes but they mostly consider the cases $p \geq 1$

Comment: Briefly scan the proofs given for $p\ge 1.$ I doubt there is anything in there that depends on $p\ge 1.$ In fact $0< p< 1$ might even be simpler.